# Poner divs en paralelo

Tags: html, css, html5, chart.js

Quiero poner los 4 divs de los textarea 2 a 2 en paralelo y los divs llamados"aforochart" y "reservaschart" también ambos en paralelo.Los divs de los charts no he puesto el código javascript porque ocupa mucho y no es necesario.
Solo quiero alinear los divs

Con css si es necesario.

Gracias

```html
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 10:00 a 12:00</span></a>
                            <text class="badge badge-dark" name="2ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="2ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
                                <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
                                </div>
          </div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 12:00 a 14:00</span></a>
                            <text class="badge badge-dark" name="3ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="3ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
                                <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
                                </div>
          </div>
 <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 14:00 a 16:00</span></a>
                            <text class="badge badge-dark" name="4ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="4ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
                                <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
                                </div>
          </div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 16:00 a 19:00</span></a>
                            <text class="badge badge-dark" name="5ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="5ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
                                <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
                                </div>
          </div>

          <div id="reservaschart"></div>
          <div id="aforochart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo del todo lo que quieres hacer pero por el nombre de las clases ¿estás utilizando [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap)? Si es así y lo que quieres hacer es lo que pienso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-6">
        <div style="padding-left:10px;">
          <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 10:00 a 12:00</span></a>
          <text class="badge badge-dark" name="2ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="2ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
          <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-6">
        <div style="padding-left:10px;">
          <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 12:00 a 14:00</span></a>
          <text class="badge badge-dark" name="3ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="3ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
          <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-6">
        <div style="padding-left:10px;">
          <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 14:00 a 16:00</span></a>
          <text class="badge badge-dark" name="4ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="4ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
          <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-6">
        <div style="padding-left:10px;">
          <a><span class="badge badge-dark">Número de Reservas de 16:00 a 19:00</span></a>
          <text class="badge badge-dark" name="5ºhora" cols="5" rows="2" id="5ºhora" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $fila['total']; ?>"><?php echo $fila['total']; ?> </text>
          <a><span class="badge badge-dark">reservas</span></a>
          </div>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-6" id="reservaschart">RESERVASCHART</div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-6" id="aforochart">AFOROCHART</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema existe que usaste lo siguiente "col-12" esto hace que ocupe el 100%
el orden correcto seria el siguiente:

```html
<div class="col-6">Bloque 1 A</div>
<div class="col-6">Bloque 2 A</div>
<div class="col-6">Bloque 1 B</div>
<div class="col-6">Bloque 2 B</div>
<div id="reservaschart col-6"></div>
<div id="aforochart col-6"></div>
```

En cambio el "col-6" ocupa el "50%" del espacio en el contenedor donde se agregue.